# Firebase Text File download error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am new to Android and Firebase. Basically, I am trying to download a file from Firebase and store it in Android storage, but I am getting a weird error `"ENOENT: No such file or directory error"`. I also have the write storage permission.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

private StorageReference mStorageRef;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("20JAN2017.txt");
    System.out.println("......"+mStorageRef);
    Uri url;

    mStorageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri)
        {
            FileDownloadTask file = mStorageRef.getFile(uri);

            file.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    System.out.println("task snapshot..."+taskSnapshot.getStorage());
                }
            });
            file.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error:"+e);

                }
            });
            file.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    System.out.println("task completed");
                }
            });
        }
    });


}
}
```

Error:

```
01-23 21:53:19.502 10974-11033/indian.stock.screener E/FileDownloadTask: Exception occurred during file download
                                                                         java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                                             at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:946)
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                                          Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                                             at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                                             at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
                                                                             at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source) 
                                                                             at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source) 
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
01-23 21:53:19.712 10974-11033/indian.stock.screener E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                                                                         An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                                                                          Code: -13000 HttpResult: 200
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you want to save that file? Put the code which shows the absolute path for saving file.

Answer (score 0):

```
mStorageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        FileDownloadTask file = mStorageRef.getFile(uri);
        ...
});
```

Is your problem. `getDownloadUrl()` returns something like: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...` while the argument to `getFile()` expects something the local filesystem can resolve `file:///tmp/...`.

The contentResolver can't resolve the HTTPS URL because it can't write the URL (it's not a file the filesystem can access).

Really, you just want to use `reference.getFile(/* appropriate local file */)`, instead of getting the download URL, or download in memory via `getBytes()` or `getStream()`;